# How to extract images from the PDF file using CPAN module in perl?

Tags: perl

I tried the following code to extract images from PDF.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::GetImages 'getimages';
my $images=getimages('getimages.pdf');
print $images;
```

Comment: And what is your Problem with it?

Comment: as am getting the following error.["getimages" is not exported by the PDF::GetImages module].am getting confused to overcome this error @Jens

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/PDF::GetImages) it exports `pdfimages` not `getimages`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method Name is 'pdfimages'.

So your code must look like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDF::GetImages 'pdfimages';
my $images=pdfimages('getimages.pdf');
print $images;
```

For more Information read the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~leocharre/PDF-GetImages-1.18/lib/PDF/GetImages.pod).

Comment: sice my output looks as follows.ARRAY(0x14f7210).Can you explain me the reason for this line@Jens

Comment: @welcomedata pdfimages Returns an Array of images. Thats why you get the Output `ARRAY(0x14f7210)`.

Comment: Is it possible to do without modules @Jens

Comment: If you implement the same functionality as the module, Yes. But it makes no sence.